# problema con seleccion de datos de pagina web con igual titulo de Class, con selenium, se tiene que hacer por nth child (creo)

Tags: css, selenium

tengo que seleccionar información de una pagina web pero lo que ocurre es que la información está contenida en "elementos CSS con igual nombre de "class"", por lo que creo que se tiene que buscar por "nth child" pero me falla la sintaxis..

me puedes ayuudar?

Gracias de antemano, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Depende de si tus elementos cuelgan todos uno detras del otro del elemento padre (como `<li>` en un `<ul>` ) que usarias `.tuclase:nth-child(2)` o si tienen elementos en medio de otro tipo, con lo que usarias `.tuclase:nth-of-type(2)`.
Si pones un cacho de codigo sera mas facil

Comment: yo uso esto:  direccion=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[@class='editable col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mb10 text-right'] ") y me coge el anterior al que quiero

Comment: la información del selector es:

Comment: #fe-informacion-izq > p:nth-child(4)
#fe-informacion-izq > p:nth-child(6)

Comment: me coge (4) y quiero (6)

Comment: si tecleo: direccion=driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//p[@class='editable col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mb10 text-right']:nth-child(6)")

Comment: InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression ".//p[@class='editable col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 mb10 text-right']:nth-child(6)" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: (por lo que se ve claro que no tengo ni idea de CSS ni HTML)

Comment: Es mejor que pongas el html en vez del CSS para ver como seria la ruta correcta del selector CSS.
Ten en cuenta que nth-child no discrimina el tipo de selector, es decir `p:nth-child(4)`no te cogera la cuarta `<p>`, sino la `<p>`que este en cuarto lugar a partir de su padre. Para coger la cuarta p tendrias que usar `:nth-of-type`